# urlencode all querystring parameters

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

Is there a way to url encode the entire URL querystring without trying to urlencode each individual querystring parameters.  Right now I'm having to rebuild the querystring with something like this:

```
foreach (string x in Page.Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
 sQueryString += x + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Params.Get(x)) + "&";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you should to do is to get the following value:

```
Page.Request.Url.Query
```

See:

    `Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.htm?date=today&<a>=<b&gt;");
    string queryString = baseUri.Query;`

The `queryString` parameter will return `?date=today&%3Ca%3E=%3Cb%3E`.

One more edit - from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx):

> The Query property contains any query
>   information included in the URI. Query
>   information is separated from the path
>   information by a question mark (?) and
>   continues to the end of the URI. The
>   query information returned includes
>   the leading question mark.
>
> The query information is escaped
>   according to RFC 2396 by default. If
>   International Resource Identifiers
>   (IRIs) or Internationalized Domain
>   Name (IDN) parsing is enabled, the
>   query information is escaped according
>   to RFC 3986 and RFC 3987.

Comment: This will give you the whole current QueryString, however if you run URLEncode on it you will lose your values since ampersands (&) would be replaced with URL-safe versions.

Comment: There is no .Query but this seems to work perfectly: Page.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

Answer (score 0):

Other than using string.Format and you having an extra & at the end of your QueryString the approach above is optimal.